# How to force ArcGIS server to create KML?

Tags: arcgis-server, kml, google-earth

Attempting to serve arcgis server (AGS) 10 sde data to Google Earth (GE).
I don't have any problem opening the service or the network link in GE on my desktop.
When I try to open in ipad device nothing happens.
Finally today I got a message "kmz not supported on iphone". 
My network links generated by AGS are all kmz.
**Is there a way to force AGS to use kml instead?**
...or has anyone been successful with AGS service on an ipad?

**EDIT:**  I do have specific reasons for using GE. I hope to negate those  with some time. However everything I have built to this point has been flex. (I was informed that we now have ipad devices).
So either rebuild all my widgets in java, or find a solution that allows kml on the ipad.
Update: I get an error if I try to open kmz,
if I unzip it and put the kml in my network link folder it just doesn't work.
if I try to publish a network link with the kml ags says no kmz found.
I guess I am on to rebuild all my widgets in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a geoprocessing tool that generates KML from a feature class.

See this: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000004n000000

Instead of saving the file to a .kmz make sure you specify a .kml

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure you cannot force ArcGIS Server to generate KML files, as it includes the symbology along with the KML.

Are you simply trying to view the service on your iPad device?  If so, have you tried the ArcGIS Javascript link? (i.e. http://host/ArcGIS/rest/services/service/MapServer?f=jsapi)  If that doesn't work, I would write/host a simple JavaScript viewer that uses the [ArcGIS API for iOS](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-iphone/api).

My answer assumes you do not have a specific reason for use Google Earth, and are just trying to view the data.

Comment: I can view the java rest endpoint.